# Android GCM "from"-parameter is empty

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Since monday evening, the "from"-parameter of my received push messages is empty. Because I only want to accept messages, which are pushed from my server (and my API key) I'm checking incoming push messages like this

```
if (extras.getString("from").equals(GoogleUtil.PROJECT_ID)) { // ... }
```

This worked fine until yesterday. I know that Google updated their GCM architecture a few days or weeks ago (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm), but what does this have to do with the empty "from"-parameter and when can it be empty? Project-ID and Server API Key were not changed.

EDIT: The problem occured again today. GCM DIAGNOSTICS also tells me, that all messages have been delivered and "acknowledged" by the device...

Comment: What is the json you are getting from GCM?

Comment: Additional info: This seems to depend on the device. Another device which is using the application receives the correct "from" parameter.

Comment: @Clairvoyant I will edit in the evening, when I'm at home.

Comment: It seems to work now, but I didn't change a line of code...

Comment: Its nice your problem solved.

Comment: Today, the problem occured again. I don't know why and how to fix it. Does anyone had similar problems?